# Function $f$ with $\{x:f(x)>c\}$ being countable union of disjoint intervals

Tags: functions, continuity

Is there a term for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>c\}$ is a countable union of disjoint intervals?

For example, if $f$ is upper semicontinuous, $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>c\}$ is an open set and thus a countable union of disjoint **open** intervals. I would like to know the one for any intervals.

---

Following Jack's comment, I googled piecewise continuity and found the following definition:

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
> $f$ is piecewise continuous if and only if for any closed interval $[a,b]$, there exists a finite subdivision $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$, where $x_0=a$ and $_n=b$, such that for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $f$ is continuous on $(x_{i−1},x_i)$.

I am struggling to show the following:

> $f$ is piecewise continuous if and only if for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>c\}$ is a countable union of disjoint intervals.

1. Only if part:
   Fix any interval $[a,b]$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
   Since $f$ is piecewise continuous, there exists $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, where $x_0=a$ and $_n=b$, such that for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $f$ is continuous on $(x_{i−1},x_i)$. Since any open set is a countable union of open intervals,
   $$\{x\in(x_{i-1},x_i):f(x)>c\}=\bigcup_{j\in J_i}I^i_j,$$
   where $I^i_j$ is an open interval and $J_i$ is a countable set. Thus,
   $$ \{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{j\in J_i}I^i_j\right)\cup\{x\in\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}:f(x)>c\},$$
   which is a countable union of intervals.
   **How can we show that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)>c\}$ is a countable union of intervals as well?**
2. If part: **I have no idea where to start.**

Could anyone help me prove it? Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks to Divide1918's answer, I figured that the if part of the statement above does not hold. Now I wonder if the following is true:

> $f$ is piecewise continuous if and only if for any $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals.

I will update once I figure it out, but I appreciate any help.

**Update:** Even the only if part does not hold. Counterexample: $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$.

It seems there is no term for functions such that for any $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals?

Comment: Informally, the term piecewise continuous is often used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only if part follows from what you have done, since $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z}[k,k+1]$. If the intervals overlap at some integer point, you may make one interval to be open and the other to be closed there, thus making all intervals disjoint.

I believe I have found a counter example to the reverse direction.

Let $f=1-\chi_C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set. Then for any $c\in\Bbb R,  \{f(x)\gt c\}\cap [0,1]$ is countable union of disjoint intervals, since it is either $[0,1], [0,1]-C,$ or $\emptyset$. But $\{f(x)\le \frac12\}=C$ contains no interval. $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]-C$, but each $x\in C$ is a discontinuity point of $f$. Since $C$ is uncountable, $f$ cannot be piecewise continuous.

Comment: Thank you! Now I wonder if the following is true: $f$ is piecewise continuous if and only if for any $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals.

Comment: I figured out it was totally wrong.