# Function $f$ with $\{x \in [a,b] : f(x)>c\}$ being finite union of disjoint intervals

Tags: functions, continuity

Is there a term for a class of functions such that for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}$ is a **finite** union of disjoint intervals? If not, are there any sufficient conditions for the property above?

cf. Pairwise continuity is a sufficient condition for **countable** union of disjoint intervals, while it is not for **finite** union of disjoint intervals ($f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$ is a counterexample).

[Function $f$ with $\{x:f(x)>c\}$ being countable union of disjoint intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828446/function-f-with-xfxc-being-countable-union-of-disjoint-intervals)

Continuity concepts do not seem to help, since $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$, which is Lipschitz-continuous, has $\{x\in[-1,1]:f(x)>0\}$ is a countable but infinite union of disjoint intervals.

---

I suggest "piecewise <s>continuity and</s> monotonicity" as a sufficient condition.

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
> $f$ is piecewise <s>continuous and</s> monotone if and only if for any closed interval $[a,b]$, there exists a finite subdivision $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$, where $x_0=a$ and $_n=b$, such that for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $f$ is <s>continuous and</s> monotone on $(x_{i−1},x_i)$.

Proof:
Fix any interval $[a,b]$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $f$ is piecewise <s>continuous and</s> monotone, there exists $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, where $x_0=a$ and $_n=b$, such that for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $f$ is <s>continuous and</s> monotone on $(x_{i−1},x_i)$. Then,
$$\{x\in(x_{i-1},x_i):f(x)>c\}=I^i,$$
where $I^i$ is an <s>open</s> interval. Thus,
$$ \{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>c\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^nI^i\cup\{x\in\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}:f(x)>c\},$$
which is a finite union of intervals.

Comment: I think being rational is a sufficient condition, but I don't think it's a necessary condition.

Comment: Simple functions sound related

Comment: Functions with derivative without accumulation point of zeroes - in particular, non-zero analytical, in particular, rational - work. But differentiability is definitely not necessary, as Weierstrass function also works.

Comment: Does (piecewise) continuous monotone functions work?